# Things with expiry date

Tags: programming

I'm a software developer and currently I'm creating an inventory application. I need to name things with expiry dates, like medicines or food, in general. In Java (the programming language I'm using) is common to name -for instance- objects you can copy as "copyable". So I wish to do the same. The questions is How are things with expiry dates generally called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can "expirable" be a word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/312081/can-expirable-be-a-word)

Answer (score 4):

Perishable, as in no good after a certain period of time.